Why does setting interval in react useEffect and then clearing it in the interval function have no effect
I have this component:


function App() {
  const deployIntervalRef = React.useRef(null);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    deployIntervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("interval handler");
      console.log(deployIntervalRef.current);
      clearInterval(deployIntervalRef.current);
      deployIntervalRef.current = null;
    },2000);
  }, []);
  
  return <div></div>;
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<React.StrictMode><App/></React.StrictMode>);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>



In my mind, it should output “interval handler” once and then stop,but it doesn't. Why？
From the second log, you can see that when clear, ref has an interval id

I've converted your sample code into a runnable snippet. It appears to work correctly. Feel free to review my edit, but I don't believe your issue is reproducible

@BrianThompson Thanks for your editing, I'll check my code again

tried to create a stacblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fuawey?file=src%2FApp.js

StrictMode strikes again

Strictmode is double mounting your component. So It's doing something like creating two intervals from the double mount, but only clearing the first one

@BrianThompson You are right, after I removed the , the component behaved as I expected, thanks; But why can't I see from the log that setInterval is executed again, The "non-null deployIntervalRef value " appears to print only once

Because it is null, that's why it can't be cleared and keeps running. The first callback sets it to null before the second interval tries to clear

Worth noting that isn't how you should use setInterval with react, you should return a function from the useEffect callback that clears it when the component unmounts...

@JaredSmith 100%, and to that effect I'm concerned future readers may interpret this as removing strict mode is a solution, when in reality it's just the answer to "why". I think I'll add that as a note to my answer

Also @MattonRoi notice I updated my answer, I incorrectly wrote that the component was re-mounting when it's really just re-rendering and re-running the effect

StrictMode is causing your useEffect to run twice, which in turn is causing a second interval to be created.
The problem is the ref is being reassigned to null before the second interval can be cleared. So your second interval runs infinitely.
Demo of problem


function App() {
  console.log('rendered')
  const deployIntervalRef = React.useRef(null);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    deployIntervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("interval handler");
      console.log(deployIntervalRef.current);
      clearInterval(deployIntervalRef.current);
      deployIntervalRef.current = null;
    },2000);
      console.log(deployIntervalRef.current);
  }, []);
  
  return <div></div>;
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<React.StrictMode><App/></React.StrictMode>);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>



Demo without StrictMode


function App() {
  console.log('rendered')
  const deployIntervalRef = React.useRef(null);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    deployIntervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("interval handler");
      console.log(deployIntervalRef.current);
      clearInterval(deployIntervalRef.current);
      deployIntervalRef.current = null;
    }, 2000);
      console.log(deployIntervalRef.current);
  }, []);
  
  return <div></div>;
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<App/>);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>



Important Note
The answer to "Why" this behavior is happening is StrictMode, but this is by no means a recommendation to remove strict mode from your application.
Instead you should use an alternative method to clear the interval. This is the exact type of thing the useEffect cleanup function is designed for.
useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    // your code
  },2000);

  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);

Another alternative (depending on your real-world use-case) is to use a timeout instead of an interval. Your current code just waits 2 seconds runs the callback, and then never runs again. If you only need it to run once just use setTimeout.
useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    // your code
  }, 2000);
}, []);

